# Ubuntu no boot logo

Tags: screen, logo

When I used the exe file to install it it works on first start. Then when I restart it and boot from it, I get a purple screen then it flashes to the login screen what happend to the ubuntu logo?

Answer (score 4):

to put it simply, the graphic driver loads slower than the rest of the system.  I fixed it with these directions.

[Get your precious Plymouth splash screen back](http://cristalinux.blogspot.com/2011/01/get-your-precious-plymouth-splash.html)

I didn't not follow the directions from this particular website, I couldn't find the one I used but these are the correct direction.  I have mine back and can now remove the "quiet splash" and see the boot messages if needed.

Edit: while there is an detailed explanation of why you might want to check out, I and going to copy and paste the instructions below in case the link expires.

> Open a virtual terminal and type the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
> ```
>
> This file may not exist, so you may be creating it from scratch now.
>
> Enter the following content on the file you opened on the previous
>   step:
>
> ```
> FRAMEBUFFER=y
> ```
>
> Close and save the file.
>
> Now, run the following command to commit the change:
>
> ```
> sudo update-initramfs -u
> ```
>
> Reboot and enjoy your Plymouth splash screen.

Comment: So i will need my gpu because mine isent working atm

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here.  The fix has nothing to do with which gpu you have.  If you can get to the log in screen your gpu is working.  The reason that you have no splash screen is that the new kernels load so fast that the DRIVERS load after the rest of the system.  This fix will get the system to wait for the graphic driver to load, hence allowing you to see the boot screen or any boot messages if you Esc. the splash screen.  The system will boot slightly slower with this fix but if you have a fairly new system you will not notice the difference.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your initial question.  after you installed you didn't see the boot screen but went to the log-in screen, you were able to log in and run Ubuntu correct??  If so then Ubuntu is installed and you can use this fix to get the boot screen to show again.

Comment: Yes i dont see the boot screen but I am able to go on the login screen i was just wondering if I can get the boot screen

Comment: Then this should work for you.