# Boot Screen logo not showing in Gigabyet 78lmt-usb3 MB

Tags: boot, graphics, logo

I recently change my PC motherboard to  Gigabyet 78lmt-usb3 and after I found ubuntu boot logo not showing ( only monitor NO SIGNAL).

I reinstall to ubuntu (14.04 and 15.04) and format complete hard disk to check, but both 14.04 and 15.04 have same problem. Currently I'm using 14.04.

**Booting Process in brief-**

1. I press Power Button.
2. Gigabyet screen
3. Blank Screen (No Signal)
4. Ubuntu Desktop.

Through *nomodeset* I can see boot logo but screen resolution is 800x600 only.

I was windows user, and I'm very new to ubuntu.... so I need help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu no boot logo](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149632/ubuntu-no-boot-logo)

Comment: I already tried all possible R&D but no success.:-(